# HtmlFormattedLabel is not converting html tags to normal text when bind the html text to a property in view model after initialized view

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

HtmlFormattedLabel is not converting html tags to normal text when binding the HTML text to a property in view model after initialized view using custom renderer in  xamairn forms. Html tags only converting if the HTML code is there while initializing the view, But not after initialized. I'm binding the value to the property. But in android project element changed event not triggering. I have an API for get the data and binding to the property when comes.I wanted to html code should convert to normal text when bind the data to the property in view model. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a sample to  reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Lucas Zhang, Please see this link.https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/02/05/awesome-xamarin-forms-label-with-html-text-formatting/ I am using this its working fine. But when i use view model. Its not converting html tags to normal text means after initialize the view. I am binding the html tags to the property which is set to the html label. That platform onelementChanged event not triggering in HtmlFormattedLabelRenderer.

Answer (score 1):

Make it with custom renderer:

For IOS,

```
var attr = new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes();
var nsError = new NSError();
attr.DocumentType = NSDocumentType.HTML;

var myHtmlData = NSData.FromString(label.Text, NSStringEncoding.Unicode);
this.Control.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(myHtmlData, attr, ref nsError);
```

For Android :

```
Html.FromHtml(label.Text).ToString().Trim();
```